# Private Function is Applying to Unspecified Workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, function, reference, private

I have a private function that is designated to declare "uniqueValues" as a function that I use in one other sub routine in the module. The Code:

```
Private Function uniqueValues(InputRange As Range)
    
Dim cell As Range
Dim tempList As Variant: tempList = ""
Dim TFS As String

Set Eingaben = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Eingaben")
Set MainWs = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Eingaben.Cells(3, 3).Value)

LastRow = MainWs.Range((Eingaben.Cells(4, 3).Value) & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
TFS = Eingaben.Cells(12, 3).Value

Set InputRange = MainWs.Range(TFS & "2:" & TFS & LastRow)
    
    For Each cell In InputRange
        cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, "/", "-")
        cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, "\", "-")
        cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, "?", "")
        cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, "*", "")
        cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, "[", "-")
        cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, "]", "")
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            If InStr(1, tempList, cell.Value) = 0 Then
                If tempList = "" Then tempList = Trim(CStr(cell.Value)) Else tempList = tempList & "|" & Trim(CStr(cell.Value))
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
    
    uniqueValues = Split(tempList, "|")
    
End Function
```

However, I have noticed that when I have other workbooks open (not active?), my whole sub routine stops working and when debugging its always stuck in this private function. I assume its applying this function to the other workbooks. I have thought of using a friend procedure or putting the sub and this function into a seperate module, but I dont think that would solve the issue. Any ideas?

Comment: The above function works on the active workbook having a sheet named as `Eingaben.Cells(3, 3).value`, on a range built according to `Eingaben.Cells(12, 3).Value` . No any other workbook may interfere, I think.

Comment: Thats what I thought too. At least that was the whole goal of always referencing like that. The whole thing works fine when just ThisWorkbook (the xlsm file with my macro) and the ActiveWorkbook (the workbook with the data that should be processed) is open. But then when I open some (not all) workbooks on the side and the whole thing messes up.

Comment: Instead of using ```ActiveWorkbook```, can you modify the function to have the desired Workbook in the call, so that you know it is looking at the correct one?

Comment: If you do not forget to activate the needed workbook, I am afraid nothing wrong should happen. Please, try inserting a simple code line: `Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.Name`, immediately after `Set MainWs = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Eingaben.Cells(3, 3).Value)`. If it is the correct one, nothing wrong should happen, I think. Or set the necessary workbook specifically, fully qualifying the necessary sheet.

Comment: Yes, with that I seem to have found the issue. The certain workbooks that cause issues when opened on the side are all workbooks in which the author (my supervisor) seems to have used volatile functions of some sort. I noticed that all these workbooks would ask to save changes even if I had just opened and closed it. So this apparently interferes with the qualification of ActiveWorkbook?

Comment: Fully qualifying the neccessary sheets would be a hassle in this case, as the macro should work for multipl workbooks with the same structure but different names and sheet names. So I guess a solution would be opening those other interefering workbooks in protected view. But already thanks for the help @FaneDuru !

Comment: Why include `InputRange` as a function parameter, if you're not going to use it, but instead `Set` it inside the function?

Comment: @TimWilliams Initially I had not set InputRange in the function, but because of the issues I describe above, I thought that setting the reference to the wb and the range specifically in the function might help. I guess I could remove that again, you are right.